# Is there a comprehensive list of all the ways to view a file's contents in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files, kali-linux, open-files

Is there a comprehensive list of all the ways to view a file's contents in linux, including both methods like cat as well as methods like whiptail where it isn't the reason it was created for?

I know of cat, whiptail, nano, head, nl and tail. I'm sure there must be over 100. Could someone please provide a comprehensive list of them?

Comment: What would be the use case for this list? There are loads of tools which are designed to work only with specific data structures, and won't work on others, i.e. `zcat` would fit your definition of "viewing a files content", but only for compressed files.

Comment: @Panki and even that depends on the version of `zcat` — some work fine on non-compressed files too ;-).

Comment: Since "viewing a file" is a simple programming task, and Unix/Linux comes with many programming tools, your "list" is unbounded (possibly infinite). Is this homework?

Comment: A comprehensive list of all programs that can run `read()`? No way. Even if you mean "all programs that can read a file and display some of the contents for human consumption" instead of just processing the data internally, there's still going to be an endless amount of them.

Comment: is there some particular reason behind asking this, some problem you're trying to solve or something like that?

Comment: There can't be "_a comprehensive list of all the ways to view a file's contents in linux_" because anyone can write a new utility to present the information in a new and shiny way

Comment: @ikkachu I was basically stuck with the babysuid questions from https://cse466.pwn.college/challenges#instance_1-1 and was trying to work out how many different ways exist in linux, because based on there, there must be at least 100 distinct ways

Answer (score 2):

```
isaacs@u50-8:~$ echo bar > foo
isaacs@u50-8:~$ cat foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ less -FX foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ more foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ sed -n l foo
bar$
isaacs@u50-8:~$ tee < foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ tail foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ head foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ awk '{print}' foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ awk '{print $0}' foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ awk '{ print $1 }' foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ awk '{}1' foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ awk '1' foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ sed 's/^//' foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ printf "%s" $(cat foo)
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ vim --cmd 'set t_ti= t_te=' +redraw +q foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ pandoc foo -o foo.pdf && pdfgrep . foo.pdf | tr -d " \t\n\r"
bar1
isaacs@u50-8:~$ grep -e ".*" foo
bar
```

As you can clearly see, there are countless ways to view a file's contents in linux, and my "list" is not comprehensive in the slightest. As waltinator pointed out, the list is probably infinite because you can do things like

```
isaacs@u50-8:~$ cat foo
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ cat foo | cat
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ cat foo | cat | cat
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ cat foo | cat | cat | more
bar
isaacs@u50-8:~$ cat foo | cat | cat | more | less -FX
bar
```

And my personal favorite

```
isaacs@u50-8:~$ echo "--[----->+<]>-.--.+++++.+++++++.[--->+<]>-----.[->+++<]>++.-.--[--->+<]>---." > printfoo
isaacs@u50-8:~$ eval $(bf printfoo)
bar
```

Besides all the various built-in functionality for printing, you can write your own unique scripts and programs.

```
isaacs@u50-8:~$ $( sleep 1; nc 127.0.0.1 1234 < foo ) & nc -l 1234
[1] 8217
bar
```

Comment: And my personal favorite in `bash` is `while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line; done < file`

Comment: @doneal24 that fails for binary files containing NUL characters, though :-( (And because you didn't double-quote `$line` it mispresents lines containing multiple adjacent whitespace - consider `line="hello    world"; echo $line`)

Comment: @roaima Yes, the quotes were an oversite. In my defense, some of the suggested methods (`grep`, `printf`) also fail on binary files.